# Selenium timeout in Volt 0.9.5pre4

Tags: ruby, voltrb, opalrb

I tried to run

```
BROWSER=firefox rspec spec
```

on [a freshly created Volt App](https://github.com/DataMelon/episode-15)

and got this error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
```

unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055)

The app hangs and raises that error after a long wait.

Is Volt Framework not locking selenium webdriver down to the correct version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution was to upgrade `selenium-webdriver`:

```
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.47.0'
```

Also, upgrading `volt 0.9.4pre9` (or `0.9.5`) will fix this as well.

```
gem 'volt', '0.9.4pre9'
```